# Notation (from combinatorics): What does $\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{b+c}{2},\frac{a+c}{2}\right)=(a, b, c)$ mean, if not $\frac{a+b}{2}=a$, etc?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

This question was taken from a course on cell (as in cells in an excel sheet) combinatorics.

> For odd positive integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, show that
> $$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}, \frac{b+c}{2}, \frac{a+c}{2}\right) = (a, b, c)$$

I assume the above parentheses refers to a set of variables, with $\frac{a+b}{2}=a$ and so on. But based on that, then this would mean that the only solutions are $a=b=c$, which I believe is not the case as it asks us to prove that the above equation holds true for all odd and positive $a, b$ and $c$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Might $(a,b,c)$ mean something like *highest common factor* or *greatest common divisor*?

Comment: Hi yambourg. You don't need to edit the title to include "SOLVED", as people can see that you have accepted an answer without even having to click on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in number theory, $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ is a common notation for the greatest common divisor of the integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$. It usually doesn't cause confusion in spite of colliding with other meanings of the notation because of the context surrounding it. That's probably the meaning in this case because that formula is true (but no trivially true) for the GCD.